# Class NameError: name is not defined

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, pythonanywhere

I am building a little website with Flask on pythonanywhere.com and a MySQL DB.

The Database is "********$registeredUser", the first table is for the user-login system ("registeredUsers").
A user is created with:

```
usr = User("n@k.com","john","muller","passwordhash")
db.session.add(usr)
db.session.commit()
```

This works...
But i want to create a 2nd Table called "comments" for some messaging.
I repeat the step:

```
com = Comment("this is a test comment")
db.session.add(com)
db.session.commit()
```

but in the first line is the error

```
r = Comment("this is a test comment")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Comment' is not defined
```

Here is the Code...

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash
from flask_login import login_user, LoginManager, UserMixin, login_required, logout_user, current_user
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["DEBUG"] = True
app.secret_key = "cjkm1093f1uomes2oipd98wmfdtwkp"
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)

#Configure DB Connection Settings
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "mysql+mysqlconnector://{username}:{password}@{hostname}/{databasename}".format(
    username="nilskreie",
    password="12345678",
    hostname="********.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com",
    databasename="********$registeredUsers",
)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE"] = 299
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "registeredUsers"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    mail = db.Column(db.String(128))
    firstName = db.Column(db.String(128))
    lastName = db.Column(db.String(128))
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    email_confirmed = db.Column(db.String(128))
    vote = db.Column(db.Integer)
    def __init__(self, mail, firstName, lastName, password_hash):
        self.mail = mail
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password_hash)
        self.email_confirmed = False
        self.vote = 0
    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)
    def get_id(self):
        return self.mail

class Comment(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "comments"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    mail = db.Column(db.String(128))
    msg = db.Column(db.String(1024))
    def __init__(self, mail, msg):
        self.mail = "place@holder.com"
        self.msg = 0
    def get_id(self):
        return self.mail
```

What could be the problem? 
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Indentation issue, so that `Comment` is defined inside `User`? Where exactly does the code that calls `User` and `Comment` occur relative to the code that defines them?

Comment: The <pre>User</pre> call and the <pre>Comment</pre> are right after the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out - not the code was the problem.

pythonanywhere has a "*Reload*" Button and an "*Run*" Button.

I always pressed "*Reload*", with "*Run*" it works!